# Golang Hello World Web App in Docker Returning 404

Tags: docker, go

I’m trying to run a simple “Hello world” Golang http app. It runs on port 6258. I’m running it in a Debian 9 Docker container. When I try to visit it in Chrome at localhost:6258 it’s just a blank page. I’ve spent hours trying to figure this out. Everything I’ve read indicates that this should work, yet it isn’t. I have no idea any more, but I'm clearly doing something wrong. Here is everything I’ve done:

I downloaded the latest Docker Debian 9 image with this command:

```
docker pull debian:latest
```

I created a Dockerfile to expose the port and set up the environment.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install sudo coreutils less vim man wget curl procps ca-certificates gnupg software-properties-common unzip libssl-dev libpcre3-dev gcc make zlib1g-dev net-tools
RUN curl -O https://dl.google.com/go/go1.10.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
RUN tar xvf go1.10.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
RUN sudo chown -R root:root ./go
RUN sudo mv go /usr/local
RUN echo 'export GOPATH=$HOME/work' >> /etc/profile
RUN echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin:$GOPATH/bin' >> /etc/profile
RUN mkdir -p $HOME/work/src/hello-world/test

EXPOSE 6258
```

I created an image using the Dockerfile by running this command:

```
docker build -t testuser/testname:testtag .
```

I made a container from that image by running this command:

```
docker run -p 6258:6258 -i -t 939e7900be22  /bin/bash
```

I ran this command to finish the Go installation (didn't seem to work if I included it in the Dockerfile):

```
source /etc/profile
```

I created the app itself (`vim $HOME/work/src/hello-world/test/main.go`):

**main.go:**

```
package main
import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
)
func helloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World")
}
func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", helloWorld)
  http.ListenAndServe(":6258", nil)
}
```

I ran the app with:

```
go run src/hello-world/test/main.go
```

When I visit localhost:6258 in Chrome, instead of showing "Hello World", it's just a blank page. Chrome inspector shows it's 0 bytes and the console shows "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

`telnet` can connect to localhost:6258. curling confirms the 404:

```
curl localhost:6258 --verbose
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:6258/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 6258 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:6258
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Fri, 22 Jun 2018 19:44:11 GMT
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

I've spent hour Googling this, but haven't found anything helpful. I'm out of ideas. I'm not great with Docker and this is my first attempt at using Go, so I won't be surprised if I've missed something obvious. Any help/advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show output docker ls ?

Comment: I have recreated your environment and everything works for me. Please show your docker ls and please tell me what's going on when you run main.go

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your request, but when I run `docker ls` it says it's not a command:
`docker: 'ls' is not a docker command.`

When I run `go run src/hello-world/test/main.go`, the terminal cursor moves to a new line without a prompt, indicating that the command is running indefinitely until I interrupt it with ctrl + c.

If I run it in the background with `go run src/hello-world/test/main.go &`, it outputs the process ID and continues to run in the background. `top` confirms it's still running as a go process, matching the provided ID. Also, thanks for your help so far!